# Increment Character Value By 1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the following data in a column of a table which is not a primary key

```
0000

0001

0002
```

I would like to increment the value to increment by 1, which means result should be

```
0003
```

using a sql statement.

How can I do this

Column data type is `varchar2`

Edit 1

```
SELECT col + 1
  FROM tab2 
  where prod_id = 'A267'
```

The result is 3, ideally it should be 0003

Comment: The question is not very clear, is this a normal column? a PK? it is indexed to be a unique value? do you want to add another row with +1 or to increment each value to +1?

Comment: Its still unclear mate, what do you want to achieve? each value +1? then a standard update set value = value+1 will do the trick.. But my guess is that I am missing your intention

Comment: @sagi I have included sql statement which I have tried in my question as Edit1

Comment: What data type is that column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Column data type is `varchar2`

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column. That is a bad idea to begin with

Comment: Store them correctly as a `number` and format them when *displaying* the values e.g. by using `to_char()`. Storing a "formatted" version is almost always a bad idea. What if you decide to suddenly display 6 leading zeros? Or some users want 5 and others want 8 digits?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree with you, however, it is impossible to change data type of column.

Comment: @user75ponic then do something like :`update tab2  set col  =  str(int(cold)+1) where prod_id = 'A267' `.  basicly convert it to Integer for the math calculation then convert it back to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LPAD fo adding '0' left side and TO_CAHR for converting number in string  (because col+1 get a number)

```
SELECT LPAD(TO_CHAR(col + 1),4, '0')
FROM tab2 
where prod_id = 'A267';
```

Comment: I have checked and work right for all string with length <=4 char

Answer (score 1):

In fact for oracle numbers 0003 and 3 are the same, difference only in output formatting
In case you want format your output or use this value as a char sequence, you can just follow to this article -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm and do something like this:

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(number, '0999')
 FROM DUAL;
```

If you want just use this value for sub-select as number don't take this difference into account.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, this didn't help resolve the issue.